# pdfs in attachment

Tags: pdf, attachfile

what is the best way to attach pdfs to my LaTeX document so that the entries are automatically written to the attachment? So far I have always solved this by simply creating a list that then reflects the order of the pdfs. But surely there is something more elegant, right?

```
\section*{attachment}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
1 62,5kHz\\
\newpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\section*{62,5kHz}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=\linewidth,trim= 40 0 60 30,clip]{pdf/625khz} %left bottom right top
\newpage
\includegraphics[page=2,width=\linewidth,trim= 40 0 60 30,clip]{pdf/625khz}
```

Comment: please clarify: is attachment meant in the sense of attaching files to the PDF a la email attachments? or do you rather refer to appendix / addendum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addendum